# Transfer docker container between two servers

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Is there an easy way to transfer a docker container from server A to server B? Seems the `docker export` command is not the right tool for that. What I am looking for is a way to take a container (container + image) with all the settings, like ports and folder mounts and transfer and run it on another server.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: No, there's no easy way to do that. What is the real problem you are trying to solve, that led you to this proposal?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, I have several docker images running on one server and sometimes it gets slow due to too much workload. I would like to transfer half of the docker images to another server that currently is just standing there without job.

Comment: You should be running something like Kubernetes that can balance workloads for you.

Comment: With a total of two servers? Isn't Kubernetes more cloud oriented?

Comment: Sure, you can run Kubernetes on as little as one server, though that's really just for developers.

Comment: Ok. Might look into that. And there transfers would be more simple? Got a link with a good how to?